# How show popup only between specific time?

Tags: javascript, popup

I want to show popup only between few hours e.g between 1pm to 3pm, 
How can I do that in javascript by geting time and using if else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var hours = (new Date()).getHours();

if (hours >= 13 && hours <= 15) {
    // show popup
}
```

Comment: this may get user PC time or any fixed time jone? @Amani

Comment: This gets current PC date and time. For more options, see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp